# React big calendar not instantly loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement the 'react big calendar' into my application. The way I am filling it up with events does work, but it only shows these events when the calendar rerenders (by pressing a button, clicking an event etc.).
My guess is that it has something to do with the useState only being filled up after the calendar has rendered, but I really have no idea on how to fix this.

I'm getting my data through an Axios request to a private API from the getCalendarData() function.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this, I cannot find something like this anywhere online.

```js
const CalendarList = (props) => {
const[calendarEvents, setEvents]= useState([])

const authAxios = axios.create({
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + props.accesToken
    }
})

useEffect(() => {
    const calendarData = getCalendarData();
    setEvents(calendarData);
}, [])

const getCalendarData = () => {
    let eventsList = []

    authAxios.get(url1).then((response) => {
        if(response.status === 200)
        {
            response.data.map((course) => {
                authAxios.get(url2).then((response) => {
                    if(response.status === 200)
                    {
                        response.data.map((assignment) => {
                            let startDate = new Date(Date.parse(assignment.due_at))
                            startDate.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)
                            const endDate = new Date(Date.parse(assignment.due_at))

                            if(!Number.isNaN(endDate)) {
                                const event = {
                                    title: assignment.name,
                                    start: startDate,
                                    end: endDate,
                                    url: assignment.html_url,
                                }
                                if(!eventsList.includes(event)) { eventsList.push(event) }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    })
    return eventsList;
}


const locales = {
    "nl-be": require("date-fns/locale/nl-be")
}
const localizer = dateFnsLocalizer({
    format,
    parse,
    startOfWeek,
    getDay,
    locales
})


return (
    <div className="calendarContainer" style={style}>
        <h2 style={{"color":props.menuColour}}>Calendar</h2>
        <div>
            <Calendar
                selectable
                localizer={localizer}
                events={calendarEvents}
                startAccessor="start"
                endAccessor="end"
                style={{height: 500, margin: "50px"}}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default CalendarList;
```

Answer (score 0):

`getCalendarData` should return a promise that resolves data. Your `useEffect` should call `setEvents` with the resolved data:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getCalendarData().then((calendarData) => setEvents(calendarData));
}, []);

function getCalendarData() {
  return authAxios.get(url1).then((response) => {
    let eventsList = [];

    // some logic

    return eventList;
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it still has the same problem.

Comment: @SuperHeavy you didn't share the details about the issue you are having. Are there any errors you see in the console?

Comment: Sorry, the problem was that the calendar does not load the items instantly. You have to click on one of the calendar elements to have it load any data. It should instantly fill the calendar up with data but it doesn't do that until after clicking on an element. There are no errors in the console.